# Read office Excel files from Azure application

Tags: c#, .net, azure

We have a requirement to read an excel sheet from the Azure worker role. I understand that we can do this using Open XML SDK. It seems we cannot use Interop assemblies (correct me if I am wrong). We need to able to read ALL version of excel (2003 and older). Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: Since you are on Azure, I assume there is a budget. One option is a third party library like the Aspose products I have used before to meet this need: http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.cells-for-.net/default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think NPOI is available for the case, because NPOI can read old excels(but I have never tried in practice). 
This is a link of NPOI http://npoi.codeplex.com/

And Open XML SDK can not read the excel (2003 and older).

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use office COM component on azure. Instead you can use some third party component, like tawman said. But if you just wanted to retrieve the data from excel I think you can use Jet DB Driver.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to also consider [OfficeWriter](http://www.officewriter.com/officewriter-free-evaluation.aspx). It can handle all the commons Excel file formats from 97 and later (no .xlsb and the like). It might be overkill if you only need to read files though.

DISCLAIMER: I'm one of the engineers who helped write the latest version.